# mod_rewrite catch all .pdf requests

Tags: mod-rewrite

Hi I have a project in which, for a short time, I need to catch all requests to download the pdfs on the site and redirect to single page (which outputs a message explaining why pdf downloads are not available).

I have tried what i thought was the logical rule:

```
RewriteRule ^\.pdf$ index.php?page=mypdfpage [L]
```

but without success.

The actual location of all pdfs is `/media/pdf/[0-9]/name_of_file.pdf` though I believe there should be a rule to catch all .pdfs no matter what the location.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The rule have to be
`\.pdf$`
the ^ means 'begins with' and . resolve to any character.
so you are catching everything which is 4 letters, and last 3 are "pdf"
If you need the name of the pdf file the rule will be something like
`(.*)\.pdf$`

Comment: hmm. I tried:RewriteRule (.*)\.pdf$ index.php?page=my_page[L] but still no success.

Comment: @user791335 1) So what happens when you request PDF file? 2) Show your .htaccess -- maybe you have placed the rule where it will not be processed (the order matters).